# Insulating near a breaker box

Tags: insulation, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

In remodeling my basement I have so far finished installing R-10 2" XPS insulation against my block walls.  My question is:  How close or how far away from the circuit breaker panel can I place the insulation?  In other words can the XPS foam board go all the way up to the side of the panel, or do I need to allow some room between the panel and the foam board?

My question is due to the fact that foam board is flammable and I wonder if the foam would cause the box and breakers to overheat if the foam board was tight against it.

Answer (score 1):

Foam board should never be exposed, it should always covered with a fire retardant layer like drywall. So if it is installed correctly, your breaker box would never come in direct contact with the XPS and you don't have a problem.  If it is exposed, then you have a larger problem then just the breaker box making contact with it.

Comment: I understand that.  It will be covered with drywall.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heat is a byproduct of energy use. The electrical panel should not be generating heat in normal circumstances and doing so would be symptomatic of  a hazardous condition.

Thus, it is normal to insulate around an electrical panel.